# Slide com imagem inicial ativa

Tags: javascript, slider, slide

Olá, estou com um problema em meu slide, ele inicia com a janela do navegador em branco e após os 5 seg começa a aparecer as imagens, e quando ele chega na ultima imagem ele teria que retornar a primeira.

Pesquisei em vários lugares, mas sempre que arrumo uma coisa, estraga outra.

Sei que tenho que jogar uma classe de ativação na primeira imagem, mas como estou informando as imagens por Js, não estou conseguindo.

o HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Slide Show</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">    
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class="banner-topo">
                <img name="slide">
                  </div>
                  <a class="prev" onClick="prevImg()">&#10094;</a>
                  <a class="next" onClick="nextImg()">&#10095;</a>
                  <br/>
                </body>

        <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

o Js:

```
var i = -1;
var images = 
          ['/img/home/banner/_perfiladeira_de_perfis_estruturais_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_perfiladeira_de_telhas_metalicas_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_maquina_de_corte_longitudinal_slitter_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_maquina_de_corte_longitudinal_e_transversal_combinado_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_linha_de_producao_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_software_profil_esquadros.jpg'];

function nextImg(){
  document.slide.src = images[(++i)%3];
  if (i>=images.length) return true; 
}

function prevImg(){
  document.slide.src = images[(i = i<=0 ? 0 : i-1)%3];
}

window.onload = () => {
  let time = 4000;
  let id_interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(nextImg()) {
      clearInterval(id_interval);
    }
  }, time);
}'
```

Comment: Porque vc não inicializa antes de entrar no setInterval, a imagem na posição 0: ; `... window.onload = () => {
  let time = 4000; document.slide.src = images[0] ...`

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além de iniciar a imagem com o caminho da primeira posição da array `images`, é preciso também aletrar o valor de `i` e em vez de usar o valor fixo `3` em `images[(++i)%3]`, substituir o 3 pelo tamanho da array, senão só irá até a terceira imagem:

```
document.slide.src = images[(++i)%images.length];
```

O correto seria:

```
var i = -1;
var images = 
          ['/img/home/banner/_perfiladeira_de_perfis_estruturais_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_perfiladeira_de_telhas_metalicas_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_maquina_de_corte_longitudinal_slitter_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_maquina_de_corte_longitudinal_e_transversal_combinado_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_linha_de_producao_esquadros.jpg',
          '/img/home/banner/_software_profil_esquadros.jpg'];

function nextImg(){
  document.slide.src = images[(++i)%images.length];
  if (i>=images.length) return true;
}

function prevImg(){
  document.slide.src = images[(i = i<=0 ? 0 : i-1)%3];
}

window.onload = () => {
   ++i;
   document.slide.src = images[0];
  let time = 4000;
  let id_interval = setInterval(() => {
    if(nextImg()) {
      clearInterval(id_interval);
    }
  }, time);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por esse detalhe!